# Adding template literals to an img src tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

```
return(<div> <img src = ${coins[0].image}> </div>);
```

Hi, so I am using react to return an image which is saved in an array that I have called coins. coins[0].length returns a url that I want to use the image of but this is throwing this error.
"JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text"
It wants me to use quotes, how can i use my array? Thanks

Comment: The question (which should be solvable with the documentation) is about React, so why is there no `react` tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [the tutorial](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#specifying-attributes-with-jsx):

> **Specifying Attributes with JSX**
>
> You may use quotes to specify string literals as attributes:
>
> ```
> const element = <div tabIndex="0"></div>;
> ```
>
> You may also use curly braces to embed a JavaScript expression in an
> attribute:
>
> ```
> const element = <img src={user.avatarUrl}></img>;
> ```

You have done neither. (You also forgot the end tag for the `<img>` component.

Also look at the syntax for [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals): Templates are delimited with backticks, you you left them out.

Thus:

```
return(<div> <img src={`${coins[0].image}`}></img> </div>);
```

That said, using a template literal here is probably pointless and you could just use the value directly (unless you need to explicitly coerce it to a string from some other data type):

```
return(<div> <img src={coins[0].image}></img> </div>);
```